# Conditional uninstall package with Burn

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

I created an application and packaged it using WiX. But this application requires a prerequisite, like SQL CE 3.5. Then I created a boostrapper using Burn. The requirement is that it will only install SQL CE if it is not previously installed in user's computer.

The problem I'm encountering is that even if it doesn't install (because it is already installed), it uninstall the SQL CE if I uninstall my application. How can I solve this?

Here is the code:

```
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\PACKED_GUID" Value="Version" Variable="SQLCE_Installed" Result="exists" />

<Chain>
  <MsiPackage Id="PkgA" SourceFile="PkgA.msi" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Visible="yes" InstallCondition="SQLCE_Installed" />
```

**EDIT:**

The bootstrapper should remove the prerequisite SQL CE only if it was installed by itself. This way (pseudo-code):

```
function install() {
  if isPrereqInstalled = false {
     call installPreReq()
     boolean bootstrapperInstalledApp = true
  }
}
function uninstall() {
  if bootstrapperInstalledApp = true {
     call uninstallPreReq()
     call uninstallMyApp()
  } else {
     call uninstallMyApp()
  }
}
```

Comment: **Comment on your EDIT** AFAIK this is no default scenario and you have to develop a solution for your self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set Permanent on the Package to "yes"

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="Enclosing1_1.msi" Id="Enclosing" Permanent="yes" Vital="no" Visible="yes">
```

Comment: My question is not properly written. The problem is that I want to remove the SQL CE if it was only my application that installed it.

Comment: The solution is to code bafunctions to handle the intended behavior properly.